# "softlink between 2 pointers in C" is this possible, need this in string sorting

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to work on string sorting based upon number of characters in a string.
What i have done is taking 5 input strings from user and storing them in 5 array elements and then finding their length using `strlen()`. Now i stored the output of `strlen(i)` where i = 0 to 4, in an array, and i need to sort that array with any sorting algorithm.
My code till finding the length of each string is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *p[5];  //array of integer pointing to string
    int x[5];    //integer array to store output of strlen()
    printf("Enter the strings to be sorted");

    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        p[i]=calloc(100,1);
        scanf("%99s\n",p[i]);  //for getting and storing user input i.e string.
    }
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("enetered  [%d] string is = %s : String size = %d\n",i, p[i], (int) strlen(p[i])); //for printing the string and its length
    }
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        x[i]=strlen(p[i]); //for storing the length of string in array
    }

    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",x[i]);
    }
#ifdef OLD
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        x[i]=p[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t %d\n",x[i],strlen(x[i]));
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Assume that x[0] corresponds to length of string p[0], 
x[1] to p[1] and similar; as x[i] is an integer array, it can be sorted. Now is there any way so that when i sort the integer array, strings coupled with the integer array by some code also get shuffled and sorted.

I tried to find out a way to implement this in another way, though i am still a learner that too at beginner level. Along with this if any one can suggest me any general algorithm for string sorting.

And my secondary question is if anyone can suggest sorting of string based upon numbers of characters in a string.

Comment: So what is the problem, just write that function.

Comment: please rephrase your question, it's hard to guess what you're actually trying to accomplish. is it that you want to have two arrays pointing at the same data without having to copy it from one array to the other one?

Comment: @xmoex He wants to whenever he changes values in x for the strings lengths to be changed as well. He just wants SO to write that function.

Comment: @Armin: Actually what i want is that when i short the array containing the length of array(which is quite easy), corresponding strings also get shorted which can be accessed if we access p{i}

Comment: When you say "short" do you mean "sort"  i.e. you want to sort your strings in order of length?

Comment: And suffled should **definitely** be shuffled

Comment: I've edited the question on the assumption that you do mean "sort".  You can always roll it back if I'm wrong, but it makes a lot more sense now :)

Comment: @JeremyP: it was my mistake..accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want directly, but you can achieve something like it with `struct`s.

Instead of two arrays, have an array of struct.  The struct is defined like this:

```
struct
{
    char* p;        // Will contain the string pointer
    size_t pLength; // Length of the string
} StringDescriptor;

#define NUM_STRINGS 5
struct StringDescriptor strings[NUM_STRINGS];
```

Initialise like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_STRINGS ; ++i)
{
    strings[i].p = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    scanf("%99s\n", strings[i].p);
    strings[i].pLength = strlen(strings[i].p);
}
```

Now you want to use [qsort()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) to sort the array.  First you define a comparator for your struct.

```
int stringDescriptorComparator(const struct StringDescriptor* left, const struct StringDescriptor* right)
{
    return left->pLength - right->pLength;
}
```

Now you can run qsort.

```
qsort(strings, NUM_STRINGS, sizeof(struct StringDescriptor), stringDescriptorComparator);
```

Now your structs and hence the string pointers in them will be in order of ascending length.  That is, they will be if there are no bugs in the code fragments above - I haven't even tried to compile any of it.

Comment: it seems that you have used qshort for string shorting too.Am i right?please correct me,becsue if i am right i can always apply, qshort from the place where i am.

Comment: qsort is a C library function that you can use for sorting any modifiable array by any criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate a string by writing a null byte after the character that you wish to become the new last character of the string. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *str = strdup("Hello, world!");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    str[5] = 0; /* length of str is now 5 */

    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Hello, world!
>
> Hello